# php loop in method

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I can't make this script loop for 5 times and stop after looping through the recursion() method. The value for $x is always 1 and the 2nd while is never reached. Could anyone give me some help to understand this please?

Thanks in advance !

```
public function recursion(){       

    $a = 0;        

    do{
        $a++;    

        echo "$a \n";
        sleep(1);
        echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
    }while($a < 5);

    $x++;
    echo "** $x **\n";

    while($x <= 5){
        echo "Going back to my method $x times \n";
        $this->recursion();  // I'd like to loop this method X times
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not passing `$x` between recursions, `$x` is undefined when you try to increment it.

Add `static $x = 0;` at the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't keep `$x`'s state.  You can make it a member of the class and reference it with `$this->x`.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot! It really helped me to understand better this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign class vars or something to keep track of $x instead of assuming it will remain available throughout the recursion?

```
private $x;
public function recursion(){       

        $a = 0;        

        do{
            $a++;    

            echo "$a \n";
            sleep(1);
            echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
        }while($a < 5);

        $this->x ++;
        echo "** $this->x **\n";

        while($this->x <= 5){
            echo "Going back to my method $this->x times \n";
            $this->recursion();  // I'd like to loop this method X times
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable you declared ($x) are private to each instance of the `recursion` method.  So, any change you make to them, does not carry over to the next call.
Since I assume you are inside an object, make those variables members of the object, thuse changing their scope from method to object. And since all calls to `recursion` are inside the same object scope, the values will carry over:

```
private $x=0;
public function recursion(){       

        $a = 0;        

        do{
            $a++;    

            echo "$a \n";
            sleep(1);
            echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
        }while($a < 5);

        $this->x++;
        echo "** {$this->x} **\n";

        while($this->x <= 5){
            echo "Going back to my method {$this->x} times \n";
            $this->recursion();  // I'd like to loop this method X times
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$x` in the method is a local variable.
So that each time you call `recursion()`, the `$x` is a complete new one. So after `$x++`, it will have the value `1`.

```
private $x = 0;
public function recursion(){       

    $a = 0;        

    do{
        $a++;    

        echo "$a \n";
        sleep(1);
        echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
    }while($a < 5);

    $this->x++;
    echo "** {$this->x} **\n";

    while($this->x <= 5){
        echo "Going back to my method $this->x times \n";
        $this->recursion();  // I'd like to loop this method X times
    }
}
```

By the way, since it is a tail recursion. It can always reduce to a loop. Something like:

```
public function loop(){       
    for($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++){
        echo "** {$x} **\n";

        $a = 0;        

        do{
            $a++;    

            echo "$a \n";
            sleep(1);
            echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
        }while($a < 5);
    }
}
```

Anyway, if you have your own reason. Go ahead.

Comment: Interesting alternative. I'll try to adapt it to my problem. Thanks